# C# socket is ignoring my SendTimeout value

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I have a Socket in a C# application.  (the application is acting as the server)

I want to set a timeout on the transmission sending. That if the TCP layer does not get an ack for the data in 10 seconds, the socket should throw and exception and I close the whole connection.

```
 // Set socket timeouts
 socket.SendTimeout = 10000;

//Make A TCP Client
_tcpClient = new TcpClient { Client = socket, SendTimeout = socket.SendTimeout };
```

Then later on in code, I send data to that socket.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Function to send data to the socket
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    private void SendDataToSocket(byte[] data)
    {
        try
        {              
            //Send Data to the connection           
            _tcpClient.Client.Send(data);              
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error writing data to socket: " + ex.Message);
            //Close our entire connection
            IncomingConnectionManager.CloseConnection(this);
        }
    }
```

Now when I test,  I let my sockets connect, everything is happy. I then just kill the other socket (no TCP close, just power off the unit)

I try to send a message to it. It doesn't timeout?  Even after 60 seconds, it's still waiting.

Have I done something wrong here, or am I misunderstanding the functionality of setting the sockets `SendTimeout` value?

Comment: Could you explain how you "power off the unit"? Did you trace the tcp messages with fiddler or a similar tool?

Comment: The documentation states "A successful completion of the Send method means that the underlying system has had room to buffer your data for a network send." (remarks of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.send?view=netcore-3.1) - so the operation 
may even complete before the first byte has arrived at the destination.

Comment: "If you are using a connection-oriented protocol, Send will block until all of the bytes in the buffer are sent, unless a time-out was set by using Socket.SendTimeout. If the time-out value was exceeded, the Send call will throw a SocketException." [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.send?view=netframework-4.8). I don't think SendTimeout is what you are looking for. You should use Socket.Poll

Comment: @Erno the client is a physical device, I simply kill its power, and it instantly dies.

Comment: @FandangoOnCore that is exactly what I want to do.  It must block until it has sent, or given an exception If it does not send in a certain time?  But that is not how it is working for me?  It will block for longer than my timeout?

Answer (score 2):

A socket send() actually does a copy operation of your data into the network´s stack outgoing buffer. If the copy succeeds (i. e there is enough space to receive your data), no error is generated. This does not mean that the other side received it or even that the data went out to the wire.

Any send timeout starts counting when the **buffer is full**, indicating that the other side is receiving data slower that you are sending it (or, in the extreme case, not receiving anything at all because the cable is broken or it was powered off or crashed without closing its socket properly). If the full buffer persists for timeout seconds, you´ll get an error.

In other words, there is no way to detect an abrupt socket error (like a bad cable or a powered off or crashed peer) other than overfilling the outgoing buffer to trigger a timeout.

Notice that in the case of a graceful shutdown of the peer´s socket, your socket will be aware of it and give you errors **if you try to send or receive after the condition was received in your socket**, which may be many microseconds after you finished your operation. Again in this case, you have to trigger the error (by sending or receiving), it does not happen by itself.

Comment: Thank you for this, Ok so in my case I am sending very little data,  10bytes at a time, maybe once every 5 minutes.  So this would actually be a disadvantage. Cause the network stacks buffer will never fill up. and even if the socket is broken, its very likely the host would have still send out those 10 bytes but they just get lost in the ether.  So with TCP where do we actually get the benefit of TCP and acking? It seems .net removes you from the low level networking layers.

Comment: @Zapnologica One major benefit of TCP is that it ensures that data is read at the same order it was sent. When no ACK is received in a certain amount of time, the data is retransmitted automatically.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis that is all good and well, but it needs to be re-transmitted within my timeout?  What good is a value arriving to a client later on, once it has already reconnected and moved on with its job?  So its seems the timeout field doesn't actually do anything? Just limits how long you can write the buffer to windows os?

Comment: @Zapnologica yes, it ensures that your application won't block indefinitely waiting for the outgoing buffer to have enough space to store the message in. A typical TCP/IP application would expect a response after having sent a message, and use a receive-timeout.